# sqlcontext failure: ``union'' expected but identifier finalresult found

Tags: scala

when writing
val tagScore = sqlContext.sql("SELECT movieid,
tagname,(eachTagCount/totalCount) AS tagScore
FROM finalresult")) 
eachTagCount,totalCount are two columns in other table

```
 `val finalresult = sqlContext.sql("SELECT MovieId,Tag AS eachTagCount, count AS totalCount FROM result ORDER BY MovieId")

    finalresult.rdd
      .map(_.toSeq.map(_+"").reduce(_+","+_))
      .saveAsTextFile("/usr/local/spark/dataset/algorithm3/output5")
     case class fine(  MovieId:Int,Tag:String,count:Int,totalcount:Int)
     val Data5 = sc.textFile("file:///usr/local/spark/dataset/algorithm3/output5").map(_.split(",")).map(p => fine(p(0).trim.toInt,p(1),p(2).trim.toInt,p(3).trim.toInt)).toDF()
    Data5.registerTempTable("finalresult")

val tagScore = sqlContext.sql("SELECT MovieId,Tag,(eachTagCount/totalCount) AS tagScoreFROM finalresult")

    tagScore.rdd
      .map(_.toSeq.map(_+"").reduce(_+","+_))
      .saveAsTextFile("/usr/local/spark/dataset/algorithm3/output6")`
```

after running this exception appear

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>       at model3.main(model3.scala)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.62] failure: ``union'' expected but identifier finalresult found

SELECT MovieId,Tag,(eachTagCount/totalCount) AS tagScoreFROM finalresult
                                                             ^
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.AbstractSparkSQLParser.parse(AbstractSparkSQLParser.scala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.DefaultParserDialect.parse(ParserDialect.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$2.apply(SQLContext.scala:211)

```
how to solve it?
```

Comment: Isn't the issue due to `AS tagScoreFROM finalresult` in the line `val tagScore = sqlContext.sql("SELECT MovieId,Tag,(eachTagCount/totalCount) AS tagScoreFROM finalresult")`?

Answer (score 0):

looks the dataframe which is defined same as registered temp table (both have some name)
`finalresult` is casing the problem as thats taking as variable instead of table.

could you please rename the variable or temporary table.

Comment: changing name of dataframe but same exception appear